# Redirect All Request from web server to another

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat8, spring-rest

I have to make an application in tomcat which core responsibility is to redirect all request coming from browser application to API server. It works like proxy server between browser application and API application. Have to write it on tomcat. How can i achieve this, do i have write a REST API application on tomcat too?

**Project Description**

Requirement is like we have two application one is developed on React, its a web-portal and the other one is on spring-boot as a backend application (json apis).
spring-boot application is going to be deployed on secure zone and web-portal is in DMZ. web-portal in on internet, backend application is on intranet. As web-portal is a CSR application so the api's calls from web-portal contains backend application IP/URI but it cannot be accessible from internet.

So i am planning to write an application on DMZ zone and it will be deployed on apache tomcat, so like when request comes at tomcat it redirect it to backend application server which is on intranet with all headers/payload and redirect response from backend server to web-portal.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up a reverse proxy which is a standard pattern. Take a look at the answers at [Reverse Proxy Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485979/reverse-proxy-java) or just search the web for "reverse proxy java".

If you are not bound to implement it in java take a look at Nginx which we use in many projects to transfer the request from the web app to the REST backend.